# React Native: Modular styling

Tags: reactjs, react-native

**foo.js** (Code block from React Native boilerplate):

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});
```

What is the best way to declare new styles from a different file **bar.js**?

1) Add a new property to `styles`?

```
//import styles from 'foo.js'

styles.forNewComponent = {
  fontSize: 30,
};
```

2) Or create new `StyleSheet` obj?

```
const StylesforNewComponent = StyleSheet.create({
  fontSize: 30,
});
```

---

When using 1) method and `console.log(styles);` the output is:

`Object {container: 3, welcome: 4, instructions: 5, forNewComponent: Object}`

Why `forNewComponent` 's value is an object but other properties have `ID` am I doing it wrong? Will I have performance issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `StyleSheet.create` instead plain object. Because StyleSheet creates something like cache.

> **static create(obj)** - *Creates a StyleSheet style reference from the given object.*

And when you use `StyleSheet` - you will be warned if you do something wrong in styles

---

And good practice is 1 component = 1 stylesheet

Comment: Thanks for the explanation!